# Index argument with createFolds in traincontrol - caret package

Tags: caret

I would like to do 10 times repeated 5-fold CV and compare results from more models. Here is one thing I don't understand:

Example of 5-fold CV:

> myFolds <- createFolds(loan_data$loan_status, k = 5)
>
> summary(myFolds)

Lenghts:

Fold1 -  2011,

Fold2 -  2012,....., Fold5  - 2012

Folds have ~ 2012 indexes which is ~ 20%

This should make 5 folds and I can use them in  *index* argument of *trainControl* function:

> myControl <- trainControl(
>     method = "cv",
>     number = 5,
>     summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
>     classProbs = TRUE,
>     index = myFolds
>   )

From documentation: **index**
a list with elements for each resampling iteration. Each list element is a vector of integers corresponding to the rows used for training at that iteration.

So does it mean, that *train* function  will in all 5 resamples train data on ~2011 rows and test on ~8044 rows? Should I use **indexOut** instead of **index** if I want 80% train and 20% test?

Second function :

> myFolds <- createMultiFolds(loan_data$loan_status, 5, 10)
>
> summary(myFolds)

Fold1.Rep1:    8047,.......

Fold5.Rep10:   8048

Folds have ~ 8048 indexes which is ~ 80%
It seems like createMultiFolds creates folds for TRAINING sets while createFolds creates folds for TESTING sets. Am I right?  In this example, question is same... Should I use *index* or *indexOut*?

> myControl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
>     number = 5,repeats = 10,
>     summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
>     classProbs = TRUE,
>     index = myFolds
>     #indexOut = myFolds
>   )

Thank you for any explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my experience/summary:

if you want to return train set, you can `createFolds(loan_data$loan_status, k = 5, returnTrain=TRUE)`

internally, `createMultiFolds(loan_data$loan_status, 5, 10)` calls `createFolds(returnTrain=TRUE)`

when you use `index` in `trainControl()` the parameters `number`, `repeats` are ignored (https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/584)

Answer (score 0):

Best case you predefine your indices via createMultiFolds.

Its important that by default - if "cv" selected instead of "repeatedcv" or repeates not defined in trainControl - there won't be repeates.

So, you have to predefine you multifold indices then set the number of repeates in the trainControl.

k - number of the folds will be automatically recognized and used

t - times (repeates) must be defined

```
multiFoldIndices <- createMultiFolds(y_train,5,3)
caretListRes <- caretList(x_train,
                          y_train,
                          trControl = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                                                   index = multiFoldIndices,
                                                   repeats = 3,
                                                   savePredictions = "final",
                                                   allowParallel = TRUE
                                                   ),
                          methodList = c("lm","rf"),
                          preProcess = c("center","scale")
                          )
```