# Grouped 7-fold Cross Validation in R

Tags: r, cross-validation, random-forest, accuracy, caret

I am searching for a grouped 7-fold cross validation function. I couldn't find it in the caret package.

I got 70 subjects performing 7 trials (Outcome variable: categorical with 7 values) = 490 observations. I trained a Random Forest with reasonable accuracy in the OOB (89%) as well as in 10 fold CV. Since the data is hierarchical / dependent (7 observations belonging to one subject) a colleague suggested it would be advisable to prevent that trials from the same subject are in the train split as well as in the test split.

What do you think, should I do 7 - fold CV grouped by subject? Meaning that one fold would allways include all trials of 10 participants?

Thanks in advance

**Edit:**
Thanks for your comment. I missed just the documentation in caret about groupKFold. Here is a code solution which worked for me

```
########################## Caret Preparation ############################
k.folds = 7
df1.folds <- groupKFold(df1$ID, k = k.folds) 
df2.folds <- groupKFold(df2$ID, k = k.folds) 
df1.control <- trainControl( # 7 Folds grouped by subject cross validation, repeated 3 times
                        method="repeatedcv", 
                        number=k.folds, 
                        repeats=3,
                        index =df1.folds)

df2.control <- trainControl( # 7 Folds grouped by subject cross validation, repeated 3 times
  method="repeatedcv", 
  number=k.folds, 
  repeats=3,
  index =df2.folds)
```

**Edit 2 (26.11.21):**
Please see the answer provided by [@otwtm](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/209594/otwtm), providing the `index` argument (as created by in my case `groupKFold` which is basically just a list of the indicies used for training) overwrites the arguments `number` and `repeats`.

```
########################## Caret Preparation ############################
k.folds = 7
df1.folds <- groupKFold(df1$ID, k = k.folds) 
df2.folds <- groupKFold(df2$ID, k = k.folds) 
df1.control <- trainControl( # 7 Folds grouped by subject
                        method="repeatedcv", 
                        index =df1.folds)

df2.control <- trainControl( # 7 Folds grouped by subject 
  method="repeatedcv", 
  index =df2.folds)
```

Comment: It makes sense, 10 is just a convention, if 7 makes more sense for your data then use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, do make sure you are testing unknown patients.

(I work with highly multivariate data also with multiple measurements per subject and have met situations where not splitting train patients vs. test patients would underestimate the prediction error by an order of magnitude!)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the accepted answer.
Just a comment on your code:

In your trainControl function you specify
`method="repeatedcv", number=k.folds, repeats=3`.
Repeatedcv will automatically create 3 different partitions of 7 folds.
However, you also specify `index=df1.folds`
As far as I understandd, this conflicts with the above since it provides your custom 7-fold partition to the function.

According to this post's answer, [Index argument with createFolds in traincontrol - caret package](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/323356/index-argument-with-createfolds-in-traincontrol-caret-package) ,
"when you use `index` in trainControl() the parameters `number`, `repeats` are ignored".

So the function will create a grouped CV (which is what you want), but not a repeated one.

Comment: Good point, and absolutely correct. I realized this a while back. However I had forgotten about this question. Thanks for improving the quality of the answer / information provided here